# WPF how to access a Class Values from another form?

Tags: c#, wpf

**Goal:**

Using `WPF` I have created a Class called `User.cs`

here it is:

```
class User
{
    public int id;
    public int access;
    public string username;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public int Access
    {
        get { return access; }
        set { access = value; }
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get { return username; }
        set { username = value; }
    }
```

At my MainWindow.xaml.cs

I create a user and assign a value.

```
User u = new User();

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  u.id = 1;
  u.access = 2;
  u.username = "User1";
}
```

**Question**

From my new `xaml` form called `Dashboard.xaml.cs`. How can I access the information saved from `MainWindow.xaml.cs` ?

**What I have tried**

At `Dashboard.xaml.cs`

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txt.Content = User.username
}
```

**UPDATE: Using MVVM:**

After some research and copying some examples here is where I got to.

**Project Tree:**

Ignore `LoginScreen` it is not used at all.

[image]

**UserModel.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Technical_Application.Model
{
    public class UserModel { }

    public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private int id;
        private int accessID;
        private string username;

        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                if(id != value)
                {
                    id = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }
        }

        public int AccessID
        {
            get
            {
                return accessID;
            }
            set
            {
                if (accessID != value)
                {
                    accessID = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("AccessID");
                }
            }
        }

        public string Username
        {
            get
            {
                return username;
            }
            set
            {
                if( username!= value)
                {
                    username = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Username");
                }
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

**UserViewModel.cs**

```
using Technical_Application.Model;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Technical_Application.ViewModel
{
    public class UserViewModel
    {

        public ObservableCollection<User> Users
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public void LoadUser()
        {
            ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

            users.Add(new User { Id = 1});
            users.Add(new User { AccessID = 1 });
            users.Add(new User { Username = "User1" });

            Users = users;
        }

    }
}
```

**UserView.xaml**

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Technical_Application.Views.UserView"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Technical_Application.Views"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment = "Left">

                <ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = Users}">

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Path = Username, Mode = OneWay}" 
                            Margin = "0 5 3 5"/>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                </ItemsControl>

            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>


**Dashboard.xaml**

<Window x:Class="Technical_Application.Dashboard"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Technical_Application"
        xmlns:views = "clr-namespace:Technical_Application.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Dashboard" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <views:UserView x:Name="UserView" Loaded="UserView_Loaded"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Dashboard.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Technical_Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Dashboard.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Dashboard : Window
    {
        public Dashboard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UserView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Technical_Application.ViewModel.UserViewModel u =
    new Technical_Application.ViewModel.UserViewModel();
            u.LoadUser();

            UserView.DataContext = u;
        }
    }
}
```

**Next...**

I need to figure out how to store information using a button click.

Comment: You should really learn to use MVVM

Comment: As a note, the backing fields of properties should usually be private, like `private int id;`

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me recommend that you use MVVM pattern which will make your life easier now and in the future.

Now for your case, you can't directly access a random objects in C# (including forms) unless you have their reference.

the forms usually have a parent/child relationship which you can use to pass information between them. So if you do this in your `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
Dashboard dash = new Dashboard(u);
dash.Show();
```

you can receive the user object in the constructor of the dashboard form. It is possible to act in the other direction and pass information from the child to the parent.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will take my time to learn MVVM pattern now.